# PowerShell module to connect to exchange premise

Tags: powershell, module, exchange-server

Unable to run exchange cmdlets from powershell when using custom module.

Hello to All,

The function bellow works fine when connecting using it withing a script; however when turn into a module it does load and all but does not recognize cmdlets such as get-mailbox.

```
Function ConnectToExchange ([string]$eXCHServer, $myCred){
  $Session = "" 

  if(!$Session)
  {      
    $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri $eXCHServer -Credential $myCred -AllowRedirection

    Import-PSSession $Session -AllowClobber 


    if ($Session.State -eq "Closed")
    {
      return
    }
 }
}#end function
```

Comment: Can you try using `Import-Module -PSSession $Sesion -Scope Global`

Comment: Hello Prasoon. I get the following error when I try that. Import-Module : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:14 char:9
+         Import-Module -PSSession $Session -Scope Global
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Import-Module], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

Comment: try importing your module in global scope. `Import-Module -Name  YourModule -Scope Global`

Comment: Nope, still does not recognized the cmdlets.

Answer (score 0):

I've been wrestling with the same problem. When you connect to exchange it creates a temporary module where the commands are stored and, I don't know why, but it doesn't load them.

Assigning a variable to the connection function and then using that to find and load the module seems to work.

```
$exc = ConnectToExchange

$excmod = Get-ChildItem -Path $env:userprofile -Filter $exc.name -recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | select FullName

Import-Module $excmod.fullname
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try your suggestion this week and report the results.